# LESS: mixin to create Blink animation, passing @color -stops

Tags: less, css-animations, mixins, less-mixins

I wish to create a CSS animation that act like "Blink effect" using LESS. My purpose is to call a single mixin passing each time 2 `@stop` colors in order to get diffent color blink depending by css class of DOM element.

Currently I have the following HTML:

```
  <p class='blink'>
    Loading...
  </p>

  <p class='blink alert'>
    <big>WARNING!!!! Operation failed.</big>
  </p>
```

And here, LESS CODE:

```
.blink
{
  .animation-blink-mixin(@dark-green,@light-green);

  &.alert
  {
    .animation-blink-mixin(@dark-red,@light-red);
  }
}
```

ANIMATION MIXIN:

```
.animation-blink-mixin (@stop1, @stop2, @time:2s)
{
  animation:animation-blink @durata infinite;

  .steps()
  {
      0% { color:@stop1; }
     50% { color:@stop2; }
    100% { color:@stop1; }
  }

  @keyframes animation-blink { .steps(); }
}
```

My problem is that both DOM elements have the same "red color" animation, instead being one *green2green* and others *red2red*.

I understood that problem is in "animation name" that is always the same. Some suggestion to reach desired behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the animation name explicitly, e.g ([codepen demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/pvqbaR?editors=110)):

```less
.blink {
    .animation-blink(blink, #080 + 200, #080);
    &.alert {
        .animation-blink(alert, #800, #800 + 200);
    }
}

.animation-blink(@name_, @color1, @color2, @time: .5s) {

    @name: ~"animation-blink-@{name_}";
    animation: @name @time ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    @keyframes @name {
        0% {color: @color1}
        to {color: @color2}
    }
}
```

Comment: you are always my hero! :-)

Comment: What is the number 200 for?

Comment: @iamchriswick [Try yourself](http://less2css.org)? (It's just a short method to lighten a color, e.g. `#800 + 200` -> `#ffc8c8` aka `rgb(255, 200, 200)`).