# LESS, generic keyframe

Tags: css, less, css-animations, keyframe

I would like to find a way to define and use generic and dynamic keyframes using LESS. Below I've done something that works but I still need to put some unique name like this .slideDown(slideDown2; @start; @height); , is there a way to make it totally generic ? (with my solution if I use the same name it will be the same for each #divid )

```
.slideDown(@name; @start; @end) {
    @-webkit-keyframes @name {
        0% { top: @start;  }
        100% { top: @end; }
    }
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#eventspromotionsButton.in {
    @width: 200px;
    @height: 200px;
    @start: 0px;
    @end: 1000px;
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
    .slideDown(slideDown2; @start; @height);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideDown2;
}
```

thanks in advance

EDIT: Pseudo code would be .slideDown(@start; @height);

Comment: Can you show a pseudo-code of what you mean by *totally generic*? I think I understand what you need but just trying to be sure before I start working on something.

Comment: But if you don't give animation-name how would the compiler know what name to assign? I am asking this because you seem to have a suffix attached to the name.

Comment: If I know how to do it I would not ask the question =/

Comment: I was not expecting you to know it. What I am trying to say is that the compiler has no way to know how many such slide-down animations you've used up and so it can't attach a suffix on its own. Maybe instead of animating the `top` property, if you animate the `transform: translateY()` you can just simply write one `@keyframes` rule with from as `translateY(0)` and to as `translateY(100%)`. Check if that works for you.

Comment: **Note:** I assumed that `@end` will be equal to `@height` based on the mixin call's arguments but you seem to have another `@end` variable whose usage I don't know. So the above suggestion may/may not work for you.

Comment: interesting suggestion, thank you

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142854/less-mixin-to-create-blink-animation-passing-color-stops/29148073#29148073